# HQL WHERE clause AND with OR

Tags: hql

I have a situation where I need to query multiple dates and see if any are close to a given date.  So I use a WHERE Clause like this.

```
FROM table
WHERE x <= :date
OR y <= :date
OR z <= :date
AND inactive = 0
```

Now the thing is the OR clause seems to pull data regardless of the AND inactive = 0

I can only think of utilizing a temp table to capture data where inactive = 0  and then use my query to pull from that.  I would really like to know if there is a better solution.

Cheers
Fargo

Comment: Does enclosing the three `OR`s in parentheses help?

Comment: Absolutely works like a charm.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:`FROM table WHERE (x <= :date OR y <= :date OR z <= :date) AND inactive = 0`